# Checking in a file clears the property value

Tags: 2010, check-in

When I checked in a document in Document Library from Excel 2013, sometimes the properties of the file have been cleared.

No all the properties are cleared, only user defined ones are.

This rarely occurs, but once occurred, the document cannot be checked out anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: Have tried switching on versioning?

Comment: Yes, I have tried versioning. The document library require check out on editing, and create version on every check in.